# Compiler generated noexcept ctor for class with members constructed with no such guarantee

Tags: c++, exception, c++14

Consider an example:

```
class ClassThatMayThrowInCtor
{
     ClassThatMayThrowInCtor()
     {
          if (g_unlucky) throw "Exception";
     }
};

class Aggregate
{
     ClassThatMayThrowInCtor m_member;
};
```

As far as my limited knowledge goes, compiler may in some circumstances in C++14 generate a default ctor that is `noexcept`.

Will it in this case, or will it understand that since member's default ctor does not provide any such guarantee, it should not either?

---

Asked for reference of the above claim (*in some circumstances...*), I've failed to find it within the standard, but [Andrzej's blog](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/) does mention:

> This does not mean that `noexcept` is useless. Compiler will annotate
>   implicitly generated member functions of your classes (constructors,
>   copy and move assignments and destructor) with `noexcept`, as
>   appropriate, and STL components will be querying for this annotation.
>   The feature will enable significant optimizations (by using move
>   constructors) even though you will not see a single `noexcept` keyword.
>   And **when compiler annotates functions with** `noexcept` **it does it**
>   **correctly** (except for destructors), so there is no risk that some
>   noexcept move constructor will throw.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: ' compiler may in some circumstances in C++14 generate a default ctor that is noexcept' - please add a reference supporting that

Comment: @DavidHaim finding a valid reference is sort of the point of this question (and then just interpreting it).

Comment: @hauron, but you are making a statement, not asking. If you do not have any references, than ask question in a different manner, like 'is compiler allowed to generate a noexcept...'

Comment: @DavidHaim http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#17

Comment: Note that you can always use `noexcept(Aggregate {})` to find out for a specific type. But of course, this only demonstrates compiler behavior, not standard requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[except.spec]**:

> 14 - [...]  If `f` is [...] an implicitly declared default constructor [...] `f` allows all exceptions if any function it directly
>   invokes allows all exceptions, and `f` has the *exception-specification* `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly
>   invokes allows no exceptions. [...]

The implicitly declared default constructor of `Aggregate` directly invokes `ClassThatMayThrowInCtor::ClassThatMayThrowInCtor()` which allows all exceptions, so `Aggregate::Aggregate()` allows all exceptions and is not `noexcept`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check this at compile time. B's default constructor is not `noexcept` in the program below:

```
struct A {
    A() {
        throw 0;
    }
};

struct B {
    A a;
};

static_assert(noexcept(B{}), "");

int main() {
    return 0;   
}
```

This program fails to compile, because the `static_assert` fails.